# Maximum intensification by refraction

Tags: refraction, approximations

Suppose that a beam of light in a medium with index of refraction $n$ reaches the surface of the medium, with vacuum on the outside. Its incident angle with respect to the normal is $\theta$. Only a fraction $\alpha$ of the energy is transmitted, the rest being reflected.  Because of this, we might expect that the transmitted ray would always be less intense than the incident one. But because the transmitted ray is refracted, it  becomes narrower, causing an additional change in intensity by a factor $\beta>1$. The product of these factors $I=\alpha\beta$ can be greater than one. I'm interested in estimating the maximum amount of intensification.

I got an approximate answer in the case of unpolarized light by using [Schlick's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlick%27s_approximation), which for small angles gives $\alpha\approx 1-(1/32)\theta^{10}$. Making some more approximations and maximizing the intensity gives an expression of the form $I=I(\theta=0)(1+k(n^2-1)^{5/4})$ for the maximum intensification, and, e.g., for $n=1.3$ I get $I=1.31$.

It would be interesting to see what can happen for larger indices of refraction, for which the small-angle approximations fail. Can anyone find anything interesting such as an approximation that holds when $n$ is not small, or asymptotics for large $n$? I don't care what you assume about polarization if it leads to an interesting result.